# Brownian Motion, Measurability of $C([0,\infty))$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, brownian-motion

**Background:**

Let $\{B(t) : t\ge 0\}$ be a Brownian motion on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.  We can interpret $B$ as a random variable $\Omega\rightarrow \prod_{[0,\infty)}\mathbb{R}$ that is $\mathcal{F}-\bigotimes_{[0,\infty)}\text{Borel}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable.

We require that $t\mapsto B(t)$ be almost surely continuous.  The book that I am reading defines this to mean that the subset $\{\omega\in \Omega : t\mapsto B(t,\omega)\text{ is continuous}\} = \{\omega : B(\cdot,\omega)\in C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})\}$ contains an almost sure subset $A\in \mathcal{F}$.

I would like to say that $B^{-1}(C([0,\infty)))$ has measure $1$.  However, since $C([0,\infty))$ is not $\bigotimes_{[0,\infty)}\text{Borel}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable, the $B^{-1}(C([0,\infty)))$ may not be measureable.

**Question:**

Is there a larger and natural $\sigma$-algebra on $\prod_{[0,\infty)}\mathbb{R}$ that makes $C([0,\infty))$ a measurable subset?

(Optional) Is there a reason why we define $B$ to be $\mathcal{F}-\bigotimes_{[0,\infty)}\text{Borel}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable and not measurable from $\mathcal{F}$ to this larger $\sigma$ algebra?

Comment: To your first question: there is a sigma algebra that works but it is not larger. It is the sigma algebra you obtain by intersecting the original sigma algebra with the set of continuous functions (might sound strange but just look it up).